# Why is some number concatenated in the Spring boot application name in Eclipse console?

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot

I have observed that sometimes, one numeric value gets concatenated in a sequential manner to the name of my Spring boot application in my Eclipse. Why does it happen and how to remove it? For example, please check the below picture.

Check the little 1 in the braces along with the project name `HibernateDemo1Application`. How can I remove this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the name of the launch configuration used to run your application.

These names are configured in the 'Run > Run Configurations...' menu.

If Eclipse thinks it needs a new configuration it uses a name based on the project name, if that already exists it adds (1), (2) ....